# Is it possible to retrieve data from a 3rd party App by my own Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm too much of an android novice to comprehend the more detailed postings wrt this topic on stackoverflow, so I hope I can ask this simple yes/no question instead.
I have my own flashcard android app and (due to lack of translation APIs, a different story ...) I thought I could utilized a 3rd party dictionary app I have installed on my phone (this is just for me, not for productation, so no concern about how this scales to other phones/envs).
So it sounds like it might be possible to launch the 3rd party app from my app, but it doesn't sound possible to retrieve data from the 3rd party app and consume it in my own i.e. I would have to know the source code of the 3rd party app to understand intent and activity names (and its manifest ?)

So here's the naive/simple question, is it possible to simply launch the app, navigate to the page/activity I'm interested in (since I assume I can't jump directly to it since I don't know the details) and 'swipe/parse' the output of that app and return to my app ?

Comment: Maybe you want to try the [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) method?

Comment: Its possible for a 3rd party app to volunteer data to other apps.  They do this by writing a ContentProvider that you can query.  If the app hasn't done that there's no way of getting at its data (unless your phone is rooted, in which case you could access their files, but you'd have to figure out its data format).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the other app has specifically taken that option into account and is ready to return something back to yours, **no**. You can't just read an arbitrary app or interact with it without permission. Which makes sense, think bank apps, email, and all sorts of personal information that could be leaked.

If the phone is rooted, as specified in the comments by @Gabe Sechan, you could read the files where they store their data, but that doesn't mean you could access their logic, for instance, with a dictionary app, it could mean that you may read cached translations **if** they stored those, but you'd still wouldn't be able to say *here's this word, give it to me translated*

Google does provide a [translations API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2) but I'm not sure if it will fit your needs.

Comment: thanks, didn't really expect (though less for security reasons, since I would still have to have permission to launch the 3rd party app, right ?) Google API isn't free anymore, but again, that's a different thread ...

Comment: You can launch, as in _start_ the app, but not interact with it. Some apps that are designed for it, such as the contacts app, or the photo gallery have special activities designed to actually **return** data to the caller

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this without the 3rd party having implemented a Content Provider. At least there is no easy way since it would be a huge security issue. Since this is a dictionary app in question, I would suggest using a dictionary API if this is a viable option for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question you want to get data from another app? Yes you can use server to retrieve and send data between apps.